# Trying to Understand Time Interpolate

Tags: interpolation, time-series, python, geometric-interpretation

I am trying to understand pandas interpolation, time interpolate. I know that it is the same as linear interpolation if the time indexes are equally spaced. But I don't understand how it works when time indexes are not equally spaced. Can someone please explain this to me? Thank you!

Edit:

Is there a way that can geometrically explain how time interpolation works?

If not, can someone please explain the formula or method that is used in time interpolate to estimate the missing value?

Comment: Time is ordinal (you can create a real coordinate associated to any timestamp) thus you can interpolate between two date, even not equally spaced. And there is more than linear interpolation available.

Comment: can you please explain in a little more detail? How could I create a real coordinate associated to any timestamp? Thank you.

Comment: If you use pandas you don't have to it will handle it for you. If you want to to it by yourself check for to_ordinal method of the date time object. Read the doc to get more details and insights.